# What is the conventional way to import own packages in Java with IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, package

I'm confused with importing custom packages in IntelliJ IDEA. I specified `CLASSPATH`, added my `package`, but nothing occured. What's wrong with my actions? And **what the common way to import packages?**

Comment: import com.org.xyz.yourCustomPackage.*; should do it.

Comment: I didn't mean name of package, but implementation of importation, because you can't merely import your package. @Amit kumar